# SQLDataAdapter and DataSet

Tags: sqlcommand, sqldataadapter

I'm requested to work with a bit of code that uses an `SqlDataAdapter`, and I was wondering if this is the right approach.(I have looked at the documentation, but it's not totally clear in my mind)

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE";
var Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet Result = new DataSet();
Adapter.Fill(Result);
```

Edit : think I found what was missing :

```
connectionString = help.Get_MyConnectionString();
Connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
Connection.Open();
```

Should work better with the connection open -.-"

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to open the connection. I would also wrap your SqlConnection and SqlDataAdapter in using blocks so that they are properly disposed.

```
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection("YOUR CONNECTION STRING"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
                "SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE", conn))
            {
                var result = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(result);
            }
        }
```